# Asymmetrical difference between sets

Tags: java

I'm working with two sets of data that contain complex java objects that I've created. Let's say that the elements contained are of type People.java, that has a String name and an int age. Let's say I have these sets:

`Set1 = [{James, 25}, {Arthur, 18}, {Anne, 22}]`

`Set2 = [{Arthur, 18}, {James, 25}]`

I'm trying to get the asymmetrical difference between set1 and set2 so that the result of that difference is {Anne, 22}. I've tried storing the elements in HashSets and using set1.removeAll(set2), but the answer equals set1. Important to note is that each element is a different instance, meaning that I created a Person object for {James, 25} in set1 and a new Person object for {James, 25} in set2 (there's a reason why they are different instances, since I'm simplifying the project's goal).

I also tried Google's Guava's [difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29), but the answer remains equal to set1.

I have two questions: 
1) Why is that happening? Is is because since they're different instances, the removeAll process considers them to be different?
2) What's a good way to get the asymmetrical difference in this case? I'm guessing using a Comparator, but I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have not overrode `equals` (and/or `hashCode`), so your `Person` instances are being compared by reference and not by value. Something like this should do (in the `Person` class):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Person) {
        Person p = (Person) o;
        return name.equals(p.name) && age == p.age;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.asList(name, age).hashCode();
}
```

With a proper `equals` and `hashCode`, you should be able to simply use `set1.removeAll(set2)` to get the desired result.

Comment: `Person instances are being compared by reference and not by value`. Well technically, they're always being compared by value. Just that, the default value is reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but you probably forgot to

```
@Override
public int hashCode()

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without overriding `hasCode()` and `equals(Object people)`,

`object 1` {Arthur, 18}  and `object 2`{Arthur, 18} with same values will considered different.

when you override below method

```
public int hashCode()
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

then such object satify this method will considered same and will occupy the set,